# How to export data from datagridview to excel

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, datagridview, export

This is a simple way to export to an excel file

i tried with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel but failed with it.Finally i found the simpler solution

```
Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bc111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Consider [SpreadSheetLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpreadsheetLight), using [ImportDataTable](https://spreadsheetlight.com/downloads/samplecode/ImportDataTable.cs).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           DataTable dataTable= new Database().SelectData("SelectAllSinhVien",lstPara);//return (DataTable) from database
            string filePath = "";

            SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();

            dialog.Filter = "Excel | *.xlsx";
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filePath = dialog.FileName;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid!!!");
                return;
            }
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext= OfficeOpenXml.LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            try
            {
                using (ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage())
                {
                    p.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Hà Văn Ri";
                    p.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Report File";
                    p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");

                    ExcelWorksheet ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

                    ws.Name = "Sheet 1";
                    ws.Cells.Style.Font.Size = 12;
                    ws.Cells.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    ws.Cells.Style.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";

                    string[] arrColumnHeader =
                    {
                        "Mã sinh viên","Họ tên","Ngày sinh","Giới tính","Địa chỉ","Điện thoại","Email"//headerText list
                    };
                    var countColHeader = arrColumnHeader.Count();
                    ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Danh sách sinh viên";
                    ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, countColHeader].Merge = true;
                    ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, countColHeader].Style.HorizontalAlignment=OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    int colHeader = 1;
                    int rowHeader = 2;
                    foreach(var header in arrColumnHeader)
                    {
                        
                        var cell = ws.Cells[rowHeader, colHeader];

                        var fill = cell.Style.Fill;
                        fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                        fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue);


                        cell.Value = header;
                        colHeader++;
                    }

                    int colIndex = 1;
                    int rowIndex = 2;

                    foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)//fields in obj
                    {
                        colIndex = 1;
                        rowIndex++;
                        ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex++].Value = dr["masinhvien"].ToString();
                        ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex++].Value = dr["hoten"].ToString();
                        ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex++].Value = dr["ngaysinh"].ToString();
                        ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex++].Value = dr["gioitinh"].ToString();
                        ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex++].Value = dr["diachi"].ToString();
                        ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex++].Value = dr["dienthoai"].ToString();
                        ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex++].Value = dr["email"].ToString();


                    }
                    Byte[] bin =p.GetAsByteArray();
                    File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bin);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Thành công");
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("thất bại: "+ex);
            }


        }
```